# TFS 2018 Add team project Admin via API using asp.net core

Tags: tfs

I'm currently trying to add a team admin in TFS from an ASP.net Core 2.0 application. The libraries for communicating for TFS are all target .Net Framework 4.6.2. Does the TFS REST api support adding team admins? Or are there TFS Nuget packages for ASP.net core? Are there any other options I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the current versions of the .NET wrappers for the VSTS REST APIs in a .NET Core application, you'll need to add the following to your `*.csproj` file to allow NuGet to fallback to using PCLs based on profiles:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PackageTargetFallback>portable-net451+win8</PackageTargetFallback>
</PropertyGroup>
```

More explanation what it does you can read [here](https://mitchdenny.com/vsts-libraries-from-dotnet-core/).

In addition, there is unofficial rest API to add a team admin:

```
https://TfsServer:8080/tfs/{collection|/{project}/_api/_identity/AddTeamAdmins__v=5
```

You can see a PowerShell script [here](https://github.com/JasperGilhuis/VSTS-RestAPI/blob/master/Make-TeamAdministator.ps1) how to use it.

Comment: This hasn't fixed the problem. I am able to add .net 4.6.1 projects successfully, just with the warning that it "may not be fully compatible with your project." Which seems to be true since the TFS package requires System.net.http.webrequest which isn't found in the ASP.net core sdk. I assume the article allows for loading those additional libraries from the .net framework but it doesn't seem to be working.